# jQuery animate (scrollTop) instantly scrolling to the top of the page and then scrolling down

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I am trying to do a smooth scroll down to a different section of a one-page website. I have a `<section>` with a class of `artist-content-section`, and a downward arrow with a class of `scroll-down`.

The problem is that when you click the downward arrow, it is instantly scrolling to the top of the page causing a "flash" of a different part of the page, **then** it scrolls down. I need to begin the scroll from my current position, not instantly scrolling to the top of the page and **then** scrolling to where I want it to scroll to.

Is anybody familiar with a fix to this?

Let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The href="#" is causing the page to jump to the top. I would just get rid of the  tag altogether inside the . You can use css :hover { cursor: pointer; } to get the same effect I am guessing you were going with by using the a tag.